# async function store data for another async function

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a small weather app that first get location from browser of the user 
and store the lat and lon in object of a class. 
mathod getAdress() call the api to transform the lat and lon values to address.

this is my class

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { keyApp , keyMap , link} from '../config';

export default class Location {
   constructor(id){
      this.id = id;
 }
  async getLocation() {
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        (navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(async position => {
            this.lat = await position.coords.latitude;
            this.lon = await position.coords.longitude;

        }));
    }
    else {
        console.log('Not able to get location..');
    }

}
async getAddress() {

     try {

        const address = await axios(`https://us1.locationiq.com/v1/reverse.php?key=${keyMap}&lat=${this.lat}&lon=${this.lon}&format=json`);

         this.address = address;
     }
     catch(e) {
         console.log(e);
     }
}
```

this is the index.js file

```
import Location from './modules/Location';
window.current = {}; //Testing purpose
const controlLocation = async () => {
  current.location = new Location(1);
  await current.location.getLocation();
  await current.location.getAddress();
  }

window.addEventListener('load' , controlLocation);
```

The error is the method get address try to fetch the data and call api without waiting for lat and lon values. 
this is the error and values are undefined

```
GET https://us1.locationiq.com/v1/reverse.php?key=MY_Private_KEY&lat=undefined&lon=undefined&format=json 400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(async position => {
  this.lat = await position.coords.latitude;
  this.lon = await position.coords.longitude;
}));
```

Using async/await like this does nothing. There are no promises involved, so nothing to await. getCurrentPosition uses callbacks for doing its asynchronous work, so you will need to wrap it in a promise yourself

```
async getLocation() {
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        const position = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
        });
        this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        this.lon = position.coords.longitude;
    }
    else {
        console.log('Not able to get location..');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accept functions as params

`this.setState((position) => {
    lat: position.coords.latitude, 
    lon: position.coords.longitude
  }`